# List content of directory (php)

Tags: php, arrays, directory

I have a folder. I want to put every file in this folder into an array and afterwards I want to echo them all in an foreach loop.
What's the best way to do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Scandir is what you're looking for
http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

```
<?php
$dir    = '/tmp';
$files1 = scandir($dir);

print_r($files1);
?>
```

Or use combination of opendir and readdir
http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php

Comment: I think this is better than `readdir`, even if it is only PHP 5. +1 because of example.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't get much easier than this

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

Don't forget to filter out hidden and parent directories (they start with a dot) on linux.

Answer (score 1):

An Alternative:

```
define('PATH', 'files/');

$filesArray = array();
$filesArray = glob(PATH . '*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);
```

This method allow you to specify/filter a by file type. E.G.,

```
define('PATH', 'files/');
define('FILE_TYPE', '.jpg');

$filesArray = array();
$filesArray = glob(PATH . '*' . FILE_TYPE, GLOB_ONLYDIR);
```

You can also get the FULL path name to the file by removing the parameter 'GLOB_ONLYDIR'

Answer (score 1):

This works for files and folders in subfolders too. Return list of folders and list of files with their path.

```
    $dir = __DIR__; //work only for this current dir
    function listFolderContent($dir,$path=''){
        $r = array();
        $list = scandir($dir);
        foreach ($list as $item) {
            if($item!='.' && $item!='..'){
                if(is_file($path.$item)){
                    $r['files'][] = $path.$item;
                }elseif(is_dir($path.$item)){
                    $r['folders'][] = $path.$item;
                    $sub = listFolderContent($path.$item,$path.$item.'/');
                    if(isset($sub['files']) && count($sub['files'])>0)
                        $r['files'] = isset ($r['files'])?array_merge ($r['files'], $sub['files']):$sub['files'];
                    if(isset($sub['folders']) && count($sub['folders'])>0)
                        $r['folders'] = array_merge ($r['folders'], $sub['folders']);
                }
            }
        }
        return $r;
    }
    $list = listFolderContent($dir);
    var_dump($list['files']);
    var_dump($list['folders']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: dwich answer is better. I will leave this just for information.

[readdir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php).

```
<?php

if ($handle = opendir('/path/to/dir')) {
    echo "Directory handle: $handle\n";
    echo "Files:\n";

    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        echo "$file\n";
    }

    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

Hope this helps.
—Alberto